# Language dropdown clickable?

Tags: jquery, html

I want to update my language switch from hover to onClick, so the dropdown can toggle active and deactive. How can I convert this one:

```
<div class="nav-wrapper">
  <div class="sl-nav">
    Sprache:
    <ul>
      <li><b>Deutsch</b> <i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <div class="triangle"></div>
        <ul>
          <li><i class="sl-flag flag-de"><div id="germany"></div></i> <span class="active">Deutsch</span></li>
          <li><i class="sl-flag flag-usa"><div id="germany"></div></i> <span>Englisch</span></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

I hope you guys can help me.

[codepen link here](https://codepen.io/clemens/pen/peyQYB)

Comment: Perhaps the suggested duplicate is not obvious... if you're not using javascript, then add `tabindex=0` to the hover items and change your css from `:hover` to `:focus`  https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pBxWmN

Comment: Thanks for the quick respons, I've tried this but the problem is, it doen't toggle.

Comment: Ok - can't see anywhere in your question that requests a "toggle".  Perhaps you could elaborate on what you *actually* want, *within the question*.

Comment: Sure, I edit my question.

Comment: I'm thinking you'll need JS to achieve this. Are you able to write JS for this ?

Answer (score 0):

I created a script that works:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("li.globe").click(function () {
        $(this).find('ul').slideToggle('medium');
    });
});
```